# Split a very short second video into multiple parts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, split

I've been looking for a lot of softwares that can split videos into multiple parts but most of them only manage to split large videos to let's say 1 or 2 minutes for each part.

What I would like to do is to actually split **a few seconds video** into, let's say, **10 or more parts** (therefore less that one second each, but still not frames).

I don't know if **ffmpeg** can be that precise or if there is any other solutions that exist.

Comment: Re-encoding acceptable?

Comment: Sure. No problem with it